# Adding array default to the end of migration - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make this migration:

```
 def up
   change_column :navigation_items, :access, 'text USING CAST(access AS text)', array: true
 end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
 LINE 1: ...ALTER COLUMN "access" TYPE text USING CAST(access AS text)[]
```

Does anybody know how to make sure the array is set to true on this migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
change_column :navigation_items, :access, :text, array: true, default: []
```

Assuming you want default value on the column to be `[]`

Comment: That's what I first tried but I get this error: `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "access" cannot be cast automatically to type text[]
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING access::text[]".`

Comment: Are you sure access is not a reserved word on pg? 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html
it says non reserved for PG, but I think worth renaming it